# Find if it's a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find, if the following set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

$C=\{(x,y,1): x, y \in R)\} $

So I have: 
$\vec{u}=(x,y,1)$, $\vec{v}=(a,b,1)$

$\vec{u}+\vec{v}=(a+x,b+y,2)$

$a+x,b+y \in \mathbb{R} $, but $2 \neq 1$ So it's not a subspace.

Is it correct?

Comment: You are correct: your calculation shows that this set is not closed under vector addition, and thus it is not a subspace. (it's not closed under multiplication by a scalar either, for that matter)

Comment: Correct :). You have shown $C$ is not closed under vector addition, hence it cannot be a subspace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's correct (although a counterexample with selected numbers would be better).

More easily, in this case, $(0,0,0)\notin C$